# B2C custom policy and boolean claimtransformation

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

How does one set up a claim transformation for this boolean transformation?

Have 2 boolean values - x and y.
If x equals true y should be false.
If x equals false y should keep it existing value.

The value of y should then be used to control the execution of orchestration steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the easiest way is to use Preconditions for the orchestration step. You basically setup two preconditions to skip the step based on your two values. If x is true, skip the step.(if x is true, it would set y to false and therefore also skip the step). If y is false, skip the step, x wouldn't matter in that case anyway.

It could look like this on the orchestration step:

```
<Preconditions>
    <!-- Skip this orchestration step if X is false  -->
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
        <Value>X</Value>
        <Value>True</Value>
        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
   </Precondition>
    <!-- Skip this orchestration step if Y is false  -->
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
        <Value>Y</Value>
        <Value>True</Value>
        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
</Preconditions>
```

Or you could transform x/y before with boolean transformations to a single claim and use it as a precondition.

More details about boolean claims tranformations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations

And more details about preconditions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userjourneys#preconditions

Another similar question: [Azure B2C custom policy conditional OrchestrationStep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900270/azure-b2c-custom-policy-conditional-orchestrationstep)

Comment: Thanks Martin. That solved my problem